# How could the predictive mean in a GP become negative when both the prior and the training target values are non-negative?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, prediction, gaussian-process

I am training a Gaussian process regression where the training target values are between 0 and 1 and the prior mean is the fixed zero function.  The predictive mean sometimes becomes negative e.g. -150 when far from the training points before getting far enough to get 0.  I understand algebraically how this could happen. According to Eq. 2.38 in:

http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf

the predictive mean becomes $\bar{f}_* = K(\mathbf{x}_*, X)(K(X, X) + \sigma^2 I)^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ when the prior mean is the zero function.  Even though all elements of $K(X, X) + \sigma^2 I$ are positive but this is not the case with its inverse.
Can someone intuitively explain why it makes sense to have negative predictive means while all the training target values are non-zero and the prior mean is zero?

Comment: K(x*, X) should be a 0-vector if x* is actually far away from the training points X.  Have you checked its values when you get a prediction of -2?  GPs are also a pain to optimize, so the inverse term could ill-conditioned.

Comment: @hahdawg Yes, you are right.  If I go far enough I get to zero but before that I get to very negative values upto -150 while the training target values are between 0 and 1 and mean of the prior is the fixed zero.  I still can't understand how this can make sense.  I will edit the question.